# Where can I put template loaders when AppDirs is set to True in Django - Django-admin-tools

Tags: django-2.0, django-admin-tools

I am attempting use a module called `django-admin-tools`. It requires me to place `'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader'` at the top of my templates. I have `AppDirs: True` which means that I can't use the `'loaders'` option in the options section of templates. Where can I put `'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader'` when `AppDirs` is set to `True`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader), when `APP_DIRS` is True, that means django just use `django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader`.

So I think you don't have to set `APP_DIRS` True. Just append that loader in `loaders` with `admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': False,
        'OPTIONS': {
            ...,
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
                ...
            ],
        },
    },
]
```